# Datatables : Ajax object file not saved after add or delete

Tags: ajax, datatables

I use Datatables to display the content of a JSON file like this :

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" }
    ]
} );
```

I use this code from the docs to be able to erase a row :

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );

$('#button').click( function () {
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw();

} );
```

The row is indeed deleted when the draw() function is called, but the JSON file isn't modified, so the deleted row will be shown again after a simple refresh. What am I missing ?

Comment: you have to remove the row from the json file too.

Comment: Enabling javasacript to modify a file on the server would be a really, really bad idea. Javascript is not intended to be allowed to do so, because of security riscs. The best you could do is to call a serverside script that are modifiyng objects.txt.